# Removing shiftIn and shiftout characters from utf8 file using java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, shift-jis

I am receiving a file with shiftJis encoding.  It has Japanese characters with shift in and shift out characters at the beginning and end of each multi byte string.

As per my requirement, I have to convert this file to utf-8 and remove the SI and SO characters from the utf-8 file?  what is the best way to do this?  Should I remove them before utf-8 conversion or after? and how do I remove it?  thanks in advance.

my javacode is as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String inFilePath = "src\\encoding\\input\\dfd02.PGP_dec";
    String filePath = "src\\encoding\\output\\";
      String utf8FileNm = "utf8-out.txt";
      String charsetName = "x-SJIS_0213";

      InputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilePath);
    
      Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, charsetName);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int read;
      while ((read = reader.read()) != -1){
        sb.append((char)read);
      }
      reader.close();

      String string = sb.toString();

      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath + charsetName + "-" + utf8FileNm);
      Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
      writer.write(string);
      writer.close();
      System.out.println("Finished writing the input file in UTF-8 format");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: SJIS -> byte[] -> UTF-8 ?

Comment: Shift-JIS code does not have shift-in and shift-out codes. Therefore, there is no need to remove it. Your code works correctly.

Comment: @ScaryWombat the file is a huge file and coverting to byte[] and removing it will impact performance. if not, then okay.

Comment: @英語は苦手 maybe theinput is not shift jis then... i do see the SI and SO characs in the data file.

Comment: It may be `ISO-2022-JP` instead of `x-SJIS_0213`.